# How to assign default value for a static default property of a class in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [default value for a static property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596344/default-value-for-a-static-property)

I am able to assign default value for a normal default property of a class.
But i am not able to assign default value for a static default property of a class like below:-

```
    public class AppInstance
{
    [DefaultValue(25)]
    public static int AppType { get; set; }
}
```

When I call AppInstance.AppType, it always return 0 instead of 25. Why? How can i solve it without using a private variable declaration?

Comment: Assign it in the [static] constructor.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596344/default-value-for-a-static-property

Comment: DefaultValue is an attribute for visual components, used usually by Visual Studio designers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DefaultValueAttribute` only tells the `WinForms` designer which value is the default value of a property of the form or of a control. If the property has another value, this value will appear **bold** in the properties window. But it will actually not set the value.

You must assign it a value in the static constructor

```
static MyClass()
{
    AppType = 25;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a static constructor. It is called automatically to initialize the class before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced.

```
public class AppInstance
{
    public static int AppType { get; set; }

    static AppInstance()
    {
        AppType = 25;
    }
}
```

Comment: To whoever downvoted this, mind telling me what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: It doesn't comment as to the problem with using the default value attribute, which is what was really confusing the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the use for an static member to be created by using `get; set;` in this scenario.  Maybe somebody else can?

So, I would probably just do this:

```
public class AppInstance
{
    public static int AppType = 25;
}
```

Comment: uh, drive by downvote. Explanation please.